# How do I make a bunch of if else statements based off the user input

Tags: java

```
public class WereWolfenstein2D {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        char c;
        String input;
        String difficulty;
        int difficulty1;
        String easy;

        System.out.println("Do you want to play? y/n");
        input = sc.nextLine( );
        input = input.toLowerCase();
        if (input.equals("y")) {
            System.out.println("Choose Difficulty ");
            System.out.println(" easy: type 1");
            System.out.println(" medium: type 2");
            System.out.println(" hard: type 3");
            difficulty = sc.nextLine( );
        }
    }
}
```

I have this code and I want to have it so if the user enters 1 then a bunch of stuff happens, 2 something else happens etc. But I'm not sure how to go about it, I'm not entirely sure how to place the if else statements or how to tell the computer to go to said statement depending on what the user types.

Comment: Look into `switch-case`

Comment: hi thanks for the reply.  Switch case seems to need  an integer at the start, how to I get the user input string to become an integer?

Comment: You can use strings in swtich statements, and if you want to convert integer to string use `Integer.parseInt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you should proceed

```
int difficulty = sc.nextInt();
switch (difficulty) {
    case 1:
        // code for easy
        break;
    case 2:
        // code for medium
        break;
    case 3:
        // code for hard
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Difficulty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extract the character at the index 0:

```
char input= difficulty.charAt(0);
```

That allows you to work with only the number that the user has typed and then you can use regular if/else statements to do your bidding or use switch statements as well.